# How to send and receive request in real time using laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new in laravel and I want to once the user1 inserts data in database the specific user2  gets **notification** that the user1 has inserted those data(demand of new vacation for example).

I do not know if I should even use **ajax** or **laravel flexible flash** notification to do that or even their is **another way** to do that.

Please tell me how should I process?

Comment: Any frontend frameworks did you use? eg. `VueJS`?

Comment: How can I know which one I use, or I have to install one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with pusher.
Here's the link

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting

Comment: we hade a problem of installation using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers) in Laravel Official Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply refer this example of [laravel model observer](https://bosnadev.com/2014/12/28/laravel-model-observers/)

Comment: Does it function like an emails box? this is what I want in fact

Comment: If you want to push to client side you need to use websockets. Here is a small example you can check it out https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/step-by-step-guide-to-installing-socketio-and-broadcasting-events-with-laravel-51

Comment: I heard about pusher do he does the matter.

Comment: which is the best one pusher or websockets?